# How to make Success dialog in php?

Tags: php, html, popup

I'm trying to implement a very simple contact form and I'm trying to implement a popup dialog when ever it submitted successfully, but not really sure how to do that so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

Before adding the dialog, I'm trying to test to print success and error message like this but some reason it's not printing.

```
 <form action="" id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Name: </label><span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="inputBox" />
<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send" />


    <?php
if (! empty($_POST["send"])) {
    $name = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    $toEmail = "hello@gmail.com";
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<" . $email . ">\r\n";
    
    if (! mail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $mailHeaders)) {
        $success = "Message successfully sent";
        echo "Hello";
    } else {
        $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
        echo "dfsi";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you submit the form using AJAX you can use the server response in the ajax callback to open your popup/dialog. With a regular form submission ( as shown above ) setting a session variable server side when the form is submitted before redirecting to the same page. On that same page code runs when it detects this session variable - then delete session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the code you have ( with minor modifications ) you could perhaps try an approach like this. It is however completely untested.

```
<!--
    unless sending a file no need to use an
    alternative `enctype`
-->
<form method="post">

    <label>Name: 
        <span class="info"></span>
        <input type="text" name="userName" class="inputBox" />
    </label>
    <!--
    
        assumed other fields exist within the form that
        were not shown but referenced in PHP later...
    
    -->
    <label>Email: 
        <span class="info"></span>
        <input type="text" name="userEmail" class="inputBox" />
    </label>
    
    <label>Subject: 
        <span class="info"></span>
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="inputBox" />
    </label>
    
    <label>Message: 
        <span class="info"></span>
        <input type="text" name="message" class="inputBox" />
    </label>
    
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />


<?php
    /*
        Check that required variables are set in the POST request
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST["send"],
        $_POST["userName"],
        $_POST["userEmail"],
        $_POST["subject"],
        $_POST["message"]
    )){
        /*
            Apparently FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is useless... do not use it.
        */
        $name = filter_var( $_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED );
        $email = filter_var( $_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
        $subject = filter_var( $_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED );
        $message = filter_var( $_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED );
        
        
        $toEmail = "hello@gmail.com";
        $mailHeaders = "From: " . $name . "<" . $email . ">\r\n";       
        
        /*
            As HTML content has already been generated
            any call to mail or header methods are likely to cause errors.
            
            Clear the buffers before sending mail and setting a session variable.
            
            The return value from calling `mail` is a boolean - 1/0 so assign that 
            to the session variable.
        */
        ob_clean();
        
        $_SESSION['status']=mail( $toEmail, $subject, $message, $mailHeaders );
        /*
            redirect back to the same page
        */
        exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: %s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) );
    }
    
    
    /* Display the popup/dialog or simply print a small message etc etc */
    if( isset( $_SESSION['status'] ) ){
        
        $value=intval( $_SESSION['status'] );
        $message=!empty( $value ) ? 'All good... message sent OK' : 'Bogus! Something went wrong.';
        
        unset( $_SESSION['status'] );
        
        //echo $message;

        // added basic dialog
        printf('
            <dialog>%s</dialog>
            <script>
                let dialog=document.querySelector("dialog");
                if( dialog ){
                    if( dialog.showModal ) dialog.showModal();
                    else dialog.setAttribute("open",true);
                }
            </script>',$message);
    }
?>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this but some reason the popup dialog is still not appearing so could you help me again pls?

Comment: This does not generate a `"popup"` message - this simply prints the `$message` variable. To generate the `popup` you would write out some javascript code using php rather than simply print $message.. If you see either status message when you run the code ( for me it was `Bogus! Something...` as my mail server is off ) then the code works... just add the popup code